# Relation between Green's function and Particular integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

Consider the differential equation,

$D_x f(x) =g(x)$ ,

The solution for this differential equation can be written using green's function as $ f(x)=\int G(x,x')g(x')dx'  +\sum_{i=0}^n C_ih_{i} (x)$

such that $D_{x} h_{i}(x)=0$,

My question is can this  "$ \int G(x,x')g(x')dx'  +\sum_{i=0}^n C_ih_{i} (x)$" related to "Complementary function  + Particular Integral  " ?

Comment: Any little help would be greatly appreciated, Please help